# Is variable assignment atomic in go?

Tags: go, concurrency

If I have two threads concurrently modifying a string field on a struct, will I always see one or the other string assigned to the field, but nothing else?

Comment: Two goroutines (not threads) concurrently modifying anything is a data race, and there are no benign data races. Always check your concurrent coded with the race detector.

Comment: I think the best way to use this is to use channels to modify the string. Have a goroutine listening on the channel for the change you want to do to the string, and where you are currently modifying the string just write the change you want to the channel.

Comment: @Topo: no, that's not the "best way". There are often very good reasons to use mutexes or atomic operations.

Comment: @JimB I know there are good reasons for using mutexes, my comment wasn't on the best way to do something like this, but on this specific example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of today, the version on June 6, 2022 of the [Go memory model](https://go.dev/ref/mem) guarantees that a memory access not larger than a machine word is atomic.

> Otherwise, a read r of a memory location x that is not larger than a machine word must observe some write w such that r does not happen before w and there is no write w' such that w happens before w' and w' happens before r. That is, each read must observe a value written by a preceding or concurrent write.

However, a string is definitely larger than a machine word, so your accesses are not guaranteed to be atomic. In this case, the result is unspecified, but it is most likely to be an interleave of different parts from different writes.

> Reads of memory locations larger than a single machine word are encouraged but not required to meet the same semantics as word-sized memory locations, observing a single allowed write w. For performance reasons, implementations may instead treat larger operations as a set of individual machine-word-sized operations in an unspecified order. This means that races on multiword data structures can lead to inconsistent values not corresponding to a single write. When the values depend on the consistency of internal (pointer, length) or (pointer, type) pairs, as can be the case for interface values, maps, slices, and strings in most Go implementations, such races can in turn lead to arbitrary memory corruption.

Note that `sync/atomic` provides not only atomicity, but also sequential consistency. As a result, for accesses not larger than machine word, `sync/atomic` only provides additional sequential consistency.

> The APIs in the `sync/atomic` package are collectively “atomic operations” that can be used to synchronize the execution of different goroutines. If the effect of an atomic operation A is observed by atomic operation B, then A is synchronized before B. All the atomic operations executed in a program behave as though executed in some sequentially consistent order.
> The preceding definition has the same semantics as C++’s sequentially consistent atomics and Java’s volatile variables.

Comment: Can you explain how `string is definitely larger than a machine word` is relevant here? At the end of the day, string is an immutable slice pointer?

Comment: @ahmetalpbalkan A string is not an immutable slice pointer. Although the language does not specified, the current implementation of a string in Go is a pointer to the payload and a field indicating the string length, which combined make an object double the size of a machine word.

Answer (score 20):

No. If you need atomic operations, there is [`sync/atomic`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/).

The [Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) will have all the related details. From the top of the Memory Model document:

> Programs that modify data being simultaneously accessed by multiple
>   goroutines must serialize such access.
>
> To serialize access, protect the data with channel operations or other
>   synchronization primitives such as those in the `sync` and `sync/atomic`
>   packages.

Comment: You didn't quote the next sentence: "If you must read the rest of this document to understand the behavior of your program, you are being too clever." The quoted section isn't describing the memory model, but suggesting the reader not be clever rather than rely on the details of the memory model. Is there anything in the document that actually says variable assignment is or is not atomic? If not, you haven't actually answered the question.

Comment: Assignment is not atomic, which is implied by the first sentence in the quoted documentation, and reinforced through the document as the conditions on observability are described. If that is unsatisfactory, I suggest you raise an issue with the go project for clarification in the documentation.