# Why is a data race being reported even if assignment is atomic?

Tags: go, goroutine, memory-model

Why is following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    str := "ab"
    strPtr := &str
    go func() {
        str2 := "cd"
        strPtr = &str2
    }()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("current address %p\n", strPtr)
}
```

producing a data race when run with `go run -race main.go`? Datarace looks like this:

```
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Read at 0x00c0000b4018 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /Users/***/main/main.go:16 +0x124

Previous write at 0x00c0000b4018 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func1()
      /Users/***/main/main.go:13 +0x7c

Goroutine 7 (finished) created at:
  main.main()
      /Users/***/main/main.go:11 +0x110
==================
current address 0xc000180000
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

Datarace is reported for read from address `0x00c0000b4018` on line `fmt.Printf("current address %p\n", strPtr)`, but at that time the `strPtr` already points to different address `0xc000180000`! How comes?

And even if, by some miracle, there would be a datarace, what I am doing here is assigning a pointer, which based on [go memory model](https://go.dev/ref/mem) should be atomic, re-quoting via [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74713769/3242721):

> As of today, the version on June 6, 2022 of the Go memory model guarantees that a memory access not larger than a machine word is atomic.
>
> > Otherwise, a read r of a memory location x that is not larger than a machine word must observe some write w such that r does not happen before w and there is no write w' such that w happens before w' and w' happens before r. That is, each read must observe a value written by a preceding or concurrent write.

Comment: One goroutine is writing to memory X, another goroutine is reading from memory X, with no synchronization between them that's by definition a data race.

Comment: *"but at that time the strPtr already points to different address 0xc000180000!"* --  You have nothing in your code that _actually_ enforces that. (time.Sleep is not an acceptable substitute for proper memory access synchronization)

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva, I somehow thought the go race test only reports actual race conditions that appeared during code execution, not the potential ones. That's why I put sleep there, not as a replacement of the proper synchronization.

Comment: A potential race is still an actual race. In theory the goroutine could be scheduled on another thread, and the OS stalls that thread for more than 2 seconds.

Comment: And note that "even if assignment is atomic" might be wrong.

Comment: @Volker for pointers it should be atomic based on go memory model. Or do you have some counter proof?

Comment: "for pointers it should be atomic based on go memory mode" no, the Go Memory Model doesn't guarantee that normal writes (or reads) of pointers are atomic. (They _are_ on all common hardware, but the do not need to be.)

Comment: @Volker just out of curiosity - could you please give an example of hardware where this is not true? I mean `...read r of a memory location x that is not larger than a machine word must observe some write w such that r does not happen before w...` - that would require a hardware where pointers are bigger than machine word if I am not mistaken, what sense would that make?

Comment: Machines where a hardware word is less wide than a pointer, e.g. 16bit CPUs hardware with a 24bit address room. Think of TinyGo . As I said: for "common" architecture this is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a datarace because you have a concurrent memory read/write operation without explicit synchronization. The pointer assignment in the goroutine is concurrent with the pointer read in the main goroutine.

The fact that a memory write for a pointer-size value is atomic is not relevant to a memory race. There is a race simply because the read operation can see the value of the pointer before the assignment, or the value after it, because there is no happened-before relationship between the memory-read and memory-write. So it is unlikely, but theoretically possible to observe two values for that pointer.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. I am just a GO beginner, but was under the impression that go race test will only report actual race conditions that happened in course of executing the code, not the potential ones.

Anyway, if I actually dont care if the `fmt.Printf("current address %p\n", strPtr)` reads the old or new value from the `strPtr`, then can the code be considered correct under such circumstances? Or is there some potential issue arising from not having explicit synchronization in place? Thanks.

Comment: A correct concurrent program is free of races by definition. So when you have a race, language spec starts to lose meaning. The behavior is undefined.

Comment: For the usecase we are dealing with it is completely acceptable whether new or old value will be read, i.e. the undefined behavior. So as long as this code doesnt produce an error we are ok. Maybe to explain my motivation: we have a web service validating tokens, many at the same time. For the validation a "config" is used, but this "config" can change, that's why we have a goroutine, periodically checking the new config in the background. At some point the pointer to config is reassigned, but we dont care if the token validation happening at the very same moment reads old or new config..

Comment: @MichalHosala: if there's no synchronization the compiler is free to optimize the assignment with no regard for external visibility, meaning the change may never be visible in other goroutines. Aside from that in more practical terms , including a race in your code means you cannot use the race detector, which is a highly valuable tool to validate your code and should not be discarded simply because you didn't want to call `atomic`

Comment: Without explicit synchronization, the compiler optimizes code within each goroutine. It is free to remove the assignment if it doesn't know it will be read later.

Comment: @JimB now this I havent thought about! All clear now, thanks both for letting me learn something new today.